# elm: flattening lists or arrays using foldr

Tags: arrays, elm, flatten

I am learning elm and was messing around trying to 
build a small bitmap editor. 
It almost works but showed very weird behaviour...
So after trying stuff out in the repl this behaviour seems
to originate here: in flattening 2D arrays.

Say I create these two **3x3 arrays**:

```
> import Array exposing (..)

> ones = repeat 3 1 |> repeat 3

Array.fromList 
    [Array.fromList [1,1,1]
    ,Array.fromList [1,1,1]
    ,Array.fromList [1,1,1]]
: Array.Array (Array.Array number)

> grid = initialize 3 <| \j -> initialize 3 <| \i -> (i,j)

Array.fromList 
    [Array.fromList [(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)]
    ,Array.fromList [(0,1),(1,1),(2,1)]
    ,Array.fromList [(0,2),(1,2),(2,2)]]
: Array.Array (Array.Array ( Int, Int ))
```

In my case `ones` is a monochrome bitmap, but having ones instead of `"#fff"`
or `{r=15, g=15, b=15}` yields the same awkward result below.
I then apply some `List.map2` to `ones` and `grid` to generate my `<rect>` elements.
To do so I flatten these 2D arrays using `Array.foldr`, 
before turning them to lists.

That's where the ... begins:

```
> flatten plane = plane |> foldr append  (fromList [])
<function> : Array.Array (Array.Array a) -> Array.Array a

> flatten ones |> length
12 : Int

> flatten grid |> length
9 : Int
```

Trying the same with lists:

```
>:reset
Environment Reset
> import List exposing (..)

> ones = repeat 3 1 |> repeat 3
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]] : List (List number)

> flatten plane = plane |> foldr (++) []
<function> : List (List a) -> List a

> flatten ones |> length
9 : Int
```

So this strange flattening does not happen with lists, yet it does not happen with the array I created using `initialize` either...
so where does this come from ???

EDIT: as suggested by Luke Woodward below this seems to be a bug in the current Array implementation see [git issue](https://github.com/elm/core/issues/205).

Comment: Please consider simplifying your question. It sounds like you're asking why folding arrays differs in behavior from folding lists. If so, here's a simplified example: https://gist.github.com/emmanuelrosa/da360b568b24d8f87b38eb2f4a2258e7

Comment: I know it's long and I'll try to do that but I was too confused. Actually there is another part to it, that is: why is it that two 3*3 arrays flatten differently? (`ones` and `grid`). Only `ones : Array` messes up while `grid : Array` and `ones : List` behave as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks to me like a bug in Elm's `Array` module ([Issue with Array.append](https://github.com/elm/core/issues/205)).

The bug will be fixed in Elm 0.19.  Until that is released, either use a third-party array package, such as [`Skinney/elm-array-exploration`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Skinney/elm-array-exploration/latest), or make do without `Array`s.